# Adding TinyMCE on the fly

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE editor. I have a div element. When an edit link is clicked, I would like to replace it with a TinyMCE editor. I added the `mceEditor class` in the javascript file that will get executed when the edit link is clicked.But it is not working. TinyMCE editor works when I have a textarea during page load. Can someone please tell me how to do it. Thanks.

```
<textarea id='answer' rows='25' cols='100' class='span-15 mceEditor'></textarea><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added it using `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl',false,'elementId')` and removed it using `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'elementId')`

Answer (score 1):

Version 4 of tinymce now uses `tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, 'elementId');` and `tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, 'elementId');`